# What amount of volatility is to be expected for validation set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I constructed an LSTM model as follows. Parameters were optimized via Optuna.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(25, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(5,5)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(23, return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(24, return_sequences=False))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.023157803318723094),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
                metrics=['mae', 'mse']
                )
history = model.fit(reshaped_train_features,
                    train_labels,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    batch_size=131072,
                    callbacks=[early_stopping, sign_accuracy_callback, checkpoint_callback],
                    epochs=100
                    )
```

The dataset is 15 GB of data originating from stocks, so I expected some volatility. I'm just not quite sure how much volatility can be chalked up to the nature of the data, or an error in my approach to building a model. I'm tracking Mean Squared Error because I'm interested in experimenting a loss function weighted 0.8 to MAE and 0.2 to MSE. With my RTX 4070 it still took roughly 31 hours to train, so I'm trying to be smart with what I change.

[image: Loss function, Loss vs Epoch]

The predicted value is calculated via a difference of two log values. i.e. log(x)-log(y). I'm considering Winsorization, but I suppose adding MSE to the loss function might help accomplish the same thing? Any feedback?

Comment: Your validation scores are fluctuating only a few tenths of a percent. It looks really good.

Comment: If you see fluctuations of multiple percentage points every epoch that's unusual. You have a nice decreasing trend that is starting to taper off. Think of it like this, if your y axis wasn't so zoomed in would you really even notice the changes?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: I completely forgot to mention that the predicted value is a difference of two log values, so I think that does effect the scaling. I'll add that to the post.